# How to place a message dialog procedure in a class and call it

Tags: wxpython

Suppose that I want to add a procedure to a class which takes a string argument and displays it (and some other stuff) in a messagebox? I've tried this:
Code:

```
import wx
import sqlite3

# Create a new frame class, derived from the wxPython Frame.
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.panel = panel

# Every wxWidgets application must have a class derived from wx.App
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):

        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "This is a test")
        frame.Show(True)

        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True

    def inform(self, s):
        wx.MessageBox(s + 'XXX', 'Info', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)



app = MyApp(0)    
app.inform("hello")
app.MainLoop()
```

Error message:
C:\chris\python\wxwidgets>python SO20140220.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SO20140220.py", line 29, in 
    app.inform("hello")
AttributeError: 'MyApp' object has no attribute 'inform'

Comment: I don't get that error, when I copy and paste your code and run it.   It looks fine and runs fine.

Comment: Note that it is not true that "Every wxWidgets application must have a class derived from wx.App".   It is perfectly fine to use wx.App unmodified.  http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#A_First_Application:_.22Hello.2C_World.22

Comment: Thanks for that insight GreenAsJade, useful as it is just day 3 with wxPython for me. I'm using Python 2.76 and wxPython 3.0. Weirdly, on retrying my code today, I get the same result as you. On checking I find that the "def inform" line in my original code is one character longer than in the code as posted and copied back to my PC. I'm using Notepad++ to edit the source and I guess I introduced a spurious character. Ouch.

Comment: Yes, python is a wonderful language, but the decision to have its block structure based on indentation is one that costs the world an immeasurable loss of productivity, and ongoing frustration.

Comment: One could use begin/end and code a preprocessor, I suppose, then add a Notepad++ or Editra command to use the begin/end to generate correct indentation. Or just learn to do it right <sigh>.

Comment: FWIW, learning to do it right as you code is the easy bit.  It's just discipline and habit.   Learning how to cut and paste puthon code right as another thing altogether.  An artform...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me on Windows 7, wxPython 2.9 and Python 2.7. However, I don't think you should be calling methods on the app object itself. You should call **inform** inside **OnInit**, like this:

```
import wx
import sqlite3

# Create a new frame class, derived from the wxPython Frame.
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.panel = panel

# Every wxWidgets application must have a class derived from wx.App
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):

        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "This is a test")
        frame.Show(True)

        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        self.inform("hello")
        return True

    def inform(self, s):
        wx.MessageBox(s + 'XXX', 'Info', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)



app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Or you could drop the whole subclass of wx.App and make your code much shorter, like this:

```
import wx
import sqlite3

# Create a new frame class, derived from the wxPython Frame.
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.panel = panel
        self.Show()
        self.inform("hello")

    def inform(self, s):
        wx.MessageBox(s + 'XXX', 'Info', wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)

app = wx.App(0)
frame = MyFrame(None, -1, "This is a test")
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your didactic examples Mike D.